# How to sort multiple indexes in an array and encode them based on value?

Tags: java

So, I have a for loop that loops through an array then performs a try/catch to see if any of those indexes can be made a long from their original string value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < recordLine.split("\t").length; i++) {
    try {
        long l = Integer.parseInt(recordLine.split("\t")[i]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
        System.out.println("Here are the Strings: " + i);
        System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + numberFormatException.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String[] splitRecordLineItems = recordLine.split("\t");
    Character[] resultsArray = new Character[splitRecordLineItems.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < splitRecordLineItems.length; i++) {
        try {
            long l = Long.parseLong(splitRecordLineItems[i]);
            resultsArray[i] = 'L';
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            resultsArray[i] = 'S';
        }
    }
```

You can then print the content of resultsArray for example using following line:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultsArray));
```